# Cannot open port on Azure VM

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM running Ubuntu 16.04. I'm developing a Django app hosted by Apache, so the production site is hosted on port 80 but the dev server is on 8000 or whatever.

At first I could access neither with my VM's public DNS; then I followed [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json) to set up the inbound security rules for both 80 and 8000. I was able to access the production site on 80 but still cannot get past 8000.

I'm thinking it's a firewall rule so I went and used ufw commands to allow port 8000. Nothing changed. Can somebody please tell me what I missed? I tried googling around but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Please run this command to check the service is running on port 8000 `netstat -ant | grep 8000`?

Answer (score 1):

We can follow this steps to check it:
1.Make sure your service is running:

`netstat -ant | grep 8000`

2.Make sure your service bind on `0.0.0.0`, if your service bind port on `localhost(127.0.0.1)`, which means it **won't** accept any connections from outside.

Comment: How am I supposed to run any command from a VM I can't connect to?

Comment: @Jiaye can you ssh to it?

Comment: That is the problem. I cannot ssh or rdp to it.

Comment: @Jiaye does that VM running? you can browse it with port 80? when you try to SSH it, which error message?

Comment: Azure Portal shows VM is running. I tried restarting and redeploying it from azure portal and made sure it shows it's running. When I ssh to it, it always hangs for a long time and then times out with "ssh: connect to host <my_host_name> port 22: Connection timed out".  I don't have a web server on that machine serving port 80 so port 80 times out too.

Comment: @Jiaye could you please reset SSH configuration via Azure portal? Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/troubleshoot-ssh-connection#use-the-azure-portal) to reset your SSH configuration.

Comment: @jiaye Can you telnet it with port 22?

Comment: telnet also times out with "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out"

Comment: @jiaye Thank you for your test, could you please check your network security group inbound rules, does port 22 added?

Comment: Yes, 22 is the first rule as default-allow-ssh.

Comment: @Jiaye Is there another VM in that vnet? if not, could you please create a new VM in that Vnet, SSH to the new VM then use the new VM to ssh the problem with private IP? by the way, if we can't use private to ssh to it, we should delete this VM and keep the VHD, then attach that VHD to the new VM, and copy (replace) the ssh configure file to the VHD, then use the VHD to re-create VM.